# unable login to website using wget

Tags: linux, bash, unix, wget

I am trying to login to a website using `wget`. the form looks like this.

```html
<form name='frmLogin' action='Login' method='post'>
  <table class='login'>
    <tr>
      <td class='label'>
        <div class='alignRight'>Username: <span class='mandatory'>*</span></div>
      </td>
      <td class='field'>
        <input type='text' name='txtUsername' size='10' maxlength='10' value='' onBlur="validatePassword(this, true)" onKeyPress="checkText(this, event)">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='label'>
        <div class='alignRight'>Password: <span class='mandatory'>*</span></div>
      </td>
      <td class='field'>
        <input type='password' name='txtPassword' size='10' maxlength='10' value='' onBlur="validatePassword(this, true)" onKeyPress="checkText(this, event)">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div class='toolbar'>
    <input type='button' class='button' name='btnSubmit' value='Login' onClick="javascript:formSubmit()" />
    <input type='reset' class='button' name='btnReset' value='Clear' />
    <input type='button' class='button' name='btnExit' value='Exit' onClick="javascript:navigateTo('index.jsp')" />
  </div>
</form>
```

I am using the below command to login and save the cookie and use that cookie to access a page. But I am getting session expired when I use that cookie.

## do the login

```
wget  --no-check-certificate --auth-no-challenge --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies cookie104.txt --header="Cookie: $cookie" --post-data="txtUsername=$name&txtPassword=$pass&btnSubmit=Login" ${site}login.jsp
```

## load the main page

```
wget --load-cookie cookie104.txt --no-check-certificate ${site}home.jsp
```

Cookie content:

```
cat cookie104.txt 
# HTTP cookie file.
# Generated by Wget on 2017-01-19 13:54:37.
# Edit at your own risk.

xyz02.com   FALSE   /dpl    FALSE   0   JSESSIONID  AA86E0BCE03A3D419953A928E590F184
```

OUTPUT from main page:

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: login.jsp?msg=Your current session has expired. Please log in again. [following]
--2017-01-19 13:54:38--  https://xyz02.com/dpl/login.jsp?msg=Your%20current%20session%20has%20expired.%20Please%20log%20in%20again.
```

Please advise what is that I am missing here. My intention is to get details from main page and send them in an email using sendmail.

Comment: Login and authentication can use many ways. You should use the excellent [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) to analyse what happens in a normal browser connection, in the 2 wget requests and what are the differences. Hard to guess without that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

302 means you are being redirected and `wget` stops there, since it is the end of a HTTP transaction.

You should use `curl` to "follow" the redirection, as in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74334/how-to-download-files-with-wget-where-the-page-makes-you-wait-for-download)

Comment: I tried curl the result is same. curl -k  -c k2 -d txtPassword=xyz123 -d txtPassword=****** -L https://xyz02.com/dpl/login.jsp
curl -k -b k2 -c k3-L https://.xyz02.com/dpl/home